# Fetch 3 Last video from youtube channel

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, class, youtube

Using [Youtube API](https://www.google.az/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php&ei=BUBvT4b4MKii4gTttoXAAg&usg=AFQjCNE82gwIqYzhYONK_YB8eMrlFopcDQ&sig2=W_QV_tQTiFVTXQuUy3wG-w), I've created class for my needs. (It works with Zend FW)

```
class youtube extends html {

    var $yt, $user;
    public function __construct($user) {
        require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
        $this->yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
        $this->yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
        $this->yt->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('timeout' => 180));
        $this->user = $user;
}
```

}

The problem is, when I use

```
$this->yt->getuserUploads($this->user)
```

on other class methods, it gets **ALL** videos. I want to get **3 last videos** of `$user`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really short on time at the moment otherwise I'd have a go using your code. This might help if you can't work it out or if no one comes back with an answer using your code.

I put together a quick and dirty solution as an answer for someone who wanted to show the thumbnail corresponding to the latest video uploaded to Youtube by a specific user - I coded a simple controller action and view that would display a video thumbnail which was a link to the video itself.

The example can easily be tweaked to show a particular number of videos by changing the

```
if($i==1) break;
```

line however there are probably more elegant ways of doing it than the way I did - as I say it was quick and dirty to answer a question.

I used the Zend_Feed_Reader class instead of the Zend_Gdata_YouTube class. In the short term it might help.

Good luck, let me know if this helped.

All the best, Dave :-D

[Link to the question with my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044292/youtube-api-get-latest-upload-thumbnail/9044906#9044906)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->maxResults = 3;
$query->orderBy = 'published';
$query->author = 'ThisIsHorosho';
$query->startIndex  = 1;

$videoFeed = $yt->getUserUploads(null,$query);
foreach($videoFeed as $videoEntry)
{
    echo $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl() . PHP_EOL;
}
```